# Intuition behind differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've just started studying multi-variable calculus and I found myself mumbling a lot over the definition of differentiability. Here's the one I'm using. A function if differentiable if
$$\lim_{\vec x \to \vec x_0} \frac{f(\vec x) - f(\vec x_0) - \nabla f\cdot(\vec x - \vec x_0)}{\|\vec x - \vec x_0\|}=0$$
Now, I recall that the gradient gives the direction of maximum increase of the function, and I understand that the term with the gradient gives, in fact, the component of the gradient in the direction of the vector $\vec x - \vec x_0$. What I do not understand is why, rearranging the limit, the limit for $\vec x \to \vec x_0$ of $$\lim_{\vec x \to \vec x_0} \frac{f(\vec x) - f(\vec x_0)}{\|\vec x - \vec x_0\|}$$ has to be precisely
$$\frac{\nabla f\cdot(\vec x - \vec x_0)}{\|\vec x - \vec x_0\|}$$Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Umm. If you require that there be directional derivatives in every direction, but do not place your strong condition on the exact value of the directional derivatives, you can get things such as this:

$$  f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2}, \; \; f=0 \; \mbox{along axes}  $$

Along the line $y=mx$ for nonzero $m,$ we have
$$ f(x,mx) = \frac{mx}{m^2 + x^2},  $$
so there is a directional derivative corresponding to that line, with value $1/m.$

The bad news is that the function is not even continuous at the origin:
$$ f(x,x^2) = \frac{1}{2},  $$
$$ f(x,-x^2) = \frac{-1}{2}.  $$

Comment: Ok, but at this point I find myself wondering whether the gradient was constructed for this precise purpose in the first place, to be in the limit of the expression I wrote in the question (which resembles the one-dimensional derivative). And, if this is the case, what is the derivation?

Comment: I kind of see it now. This is equivalent to asking that the directional derivatives (at the time of posting, I hadn't read the paragraph of directional derivatives, it was later in my book with respect to the definition of differentiability) are the dot product of the gradient with the unit vector (for purposes of simplicity) which gives the direction. It is indeed becoming much clearer, thank you for the example.